# Qt Creator: No valid kits for Android found

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator

After downloading the release candidate of QT android (windows 5.1) I decided to start QT Creator and try to make an android project (something small to see if it works). After following the tutorial I have added all (except for mips) android kits.

When I make a regular QT Application it tells me it sees all the android kits and if I use that it launches the emulator.

The problem however is that when I create a QT mobile application it tells me there are no valid kits.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a great answer for you as I'm very new to Qt-Creator, but I noticed that the "GUI Applications" have both Desktop and Android support. If you select GUI you'll have the option to configure the kits and select Android ARM 5/6/7 or x86 under your kits.

You can select Android or play around with both Desktop and Android to start out. I'm in the middle of playing with a "Hello World" example and trying to deploy to a Nexus 7. This definitely launches the AVD though I've had little success actually connecting to it at the moment.

Hopefully this pushes you past the initial hump.

Comment: The problem with the "GUI application" is that it can actually deploy to android (as arm) but will always result in errors when installed on the device (even hello world/empty app).

Comment: It would seem like the old rc was not quite ready for windows deployment yet. Using the newer version (june 2013) made it possible to actually create "working" .apk files.

Answer (score 4):

The "Mobile Application" kit is a left-over from older Qt versions, and should not be used anymore. In Qt Creator 2.8 it has been removed to avoid this confusion.

Just use any of the regular templates, such as "Qt GUI Application", "Qt Quick 2 Application" or "Empty Qt Project" to start from a completely clean slate. If you have problems using these templates, then those issues need to be addressed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need that kind of project?

Extracted from [QtCreator : Creating Projects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-project-creating.html)

*Mobile Qt Application*

*Use Qt Designer forms to design a Qt widget based user interface for mobile devices and C++ to implement the application logic. Select this template to develop for devices that support **only Qt 4.6.x***

QTcreator helps you to developt QT apps, then you choose which platform you would deploy to, so I would recommend you to read Android specific sections from this links:

- [QtCreator : Deploying to Mobile Devices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-deployment.html)
- [QtCreator : Connecting Mobile Devices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-connecting-mobile.html)

Comment: Pretty sure as the alternative is not willing to be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with linking the kits library with qt.